# Swiftui mapmarker missing arguments error

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm making an application in swiftui, I added maps, but I'm having trouble with mapmarker, can you help?

**The error is at the bottom of the code section.**

```
//
//  depremHaritasi.swift
//  deprembilgisistemi
//
//  Created by Tugay Asan on 1.03.2022.
//

import SwiftUI
import MapKit


struct depremHaritasi: View {

    
    let id: UUID
        let location: CLLocationCoordinate2D
        init(id: UUID = UUID(), lat: Double, long: Double) {
            self.id = id
            self.location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
                latitude: lat,
                longitude: long)
        }
    
        @State var quakes: [EarthQuake] = []
    
        @State var coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(
              center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.9520281, longitude: 35.6980142),
              span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 30, longitudeDelta: 10))

            var body: some View {
                Map(coordinateRegion: $coordinateRegion)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .onAppear {
                Api().getEarthQuake { (quakes) in
                    self.quakes = quakes
                }
            }
    }
}


struct depremHaritasi_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        depremHaritas()   //ERROR//Missing arguments for parameters 'lat', 'long' in call
    }
}
```

I tried adding the mapmarker but got a "missing arguments" error. I tried looking at different forums but it didn't work. I want the mapmarker to appear on the map.

Comment: The error is telling you you need to include parameters for `lat` and `long` at the call site. So: `depremHaritas(lat: 0, long: 0)` or something like that. Unrelated, but you should not be calling something like `Api().getEarthQuake` within your view hierarchy like that. It should probably go in `onAppear { }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

struct `depremHaritas` init takes 3 arguments **id** ,**lat** and **long**. Argument **id** has a default value so it can be skipped , but however, lat and long don't have default values. You have to explicitly provide the value to when you initialize.

```
init(id: UUID = UUID(), lat: Double, long: Double)
```

So , your code should be :

```
struct depremHaritasi_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        depremHaritas(lat:0.0 , long:0.0)
    }
}
```

Or another way is to provide default values for lat and long arguments in init as below :

```
init(id: UUID = UUID(), lat: Double = 0.0, long: Double = 0.0)
```

In this case, your will not face error for your call.

Comment: Thank you, it solved my error, but it doesn't give me what I want, I gave up on swift interface. I will move my project to the Storyboard interface. There are many example videos on the storyboard, but there are not many example videos from the swift interface :( Thank you anyway.